# How to return JSON in a file upload operation

Tags: moqui

I am uploading a file and everything uploads fine. I want to return a JSON object with the primary key defined, so I do this:

ec.web.sendJsonResponse( "{offerId: '${offer.offerId}'}")

which packages things the way my javascript receiving code expects (because it is a file upload op), but it wraps in like this:

```
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
        <textarea>{offerId: '100030'}</textarea></pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

and the "pre" tag keeps my "getElementsByTagName" from finding the "textarea" element.

I know that WebResource.sendJsonResponse is not adding it. It is setting the contentType to json and the receiving code is complaining because it is expecting a DOM object (error> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json:)

How do I resolve this? I guess this is really a J2EE question, but it might happen to someone else in moqui.

Comment: To answer this it would be helpful to see more of the server side code than just the setJsonResponse() call. In other words, where it is called from and if in a transition how is the response defined? The result included is very strange, with a plain JSON response there should be no HTML whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was pretty simple.

```
     String resp = "<textarea>{\"offerId\": \"${offer.offerId}\"}</textarea>"
     //ec.web.sendJsonResponse(resp)
     ec.web.response.writer.write(resp)
```

Answer (score 0):

In moqui, ec.web.sendJsonResponse is designed to send back the JSON response. so it is simple in where you deal with the upload in the transition of screen, you may add:

```
def respMap = [:]
respMap.put("offerId", offer.offerId)
ec.web.sendJsonResponse(respMap)
```

Meanwhile the default-response type shall be defined as "none"

```
<default-response type="none"/>
```

and you may use respMap to compose any kind of more complex JSON object, then use ec.web.sendJsonResponse method which will automatically send response map content to JSON response.